# EIP: AddressLimitExceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I have a CloudFormation template that spins up an EC2 instance for RStudio Server.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: Sets up an RStudio and Shiny environment on AWS

Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Description: Instance type for RStudio. Default is t2.micro.
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
      - t2.xlarge
      - t2.2xlarge
      - m4.large
      - m4.xlarge
      - m4.2xlarge
      - m4.4xlarge
      - m4.10xlarge
      - m4.16xlarge
      - c4.large
      - c4.xlarge
      - c4.2xlarge
      - c4.4xlarge
      - c4.8xlarge
      - r4.large
      - r4.xlarge
      - r4.2xlarge
      - r4.4xlarge
      - r4.8xlarge
      - r4.16xlarge
      - g2.2xlarge
      - g2.8xlarge
      - p2.xlarge
      - p2.8xlarge
      - p2.16xlarge
      - g3.4xlarge
      - g3.8xlarge
      - g3.16xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: Valid instance type in the t2, m4, c4, r4, g2, p2, and g3 families
    Default: t2.micro
  ImageId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
    Description: Amazon Linux Image ID. Default is for 2017.03.01 (HVM). N.B. If you want more storage then you should update your image
    Default: ami-4fffc834
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: VPC this server will reside in
  InitialUser:
    Type: String
    Description: User Name for RStudio
  InitialPassword:
    Type: String
    Description: Password for RStudio. Please keep in your records as this will not be echoed in the CloudFormation Console
    NoEcho: True
  RStatsS3Bucket:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the S3 bucket
  KeyPair:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    Description: Amazon EC2 Key Pair
  SubnetId:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
    Description: Subnet ID your instance will launch in. Should be Internet accessible for the purposes of this demo.

Resources:
  RStatsS3ReadPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: RStatsS3ReadPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - "s3:ListBucket"
            Resource:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${RStatsS3Bucket}"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - "s3:PutObject"
            - "s3:GetObject"
            - "s3:DeleteObject"
            Resource:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${RStatsS3Bucket}/*"
      Roles:
      - !Ref RStatsS3ReadRole

  RStatsS3ReadRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"


  RstatsEC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          IpProtocol: tcp
        - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          FromPort: 8787
          ToPort: 8787
          IpProtocol: tcp
        - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          FromPort: 3838
          ToPort: 3838
          IpProtocol: tcp
      GroupDescription: RStudio and Shiny Security Group
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId

  RStatsEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: !Ref VpcId

  RStatsEIPAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt RStatsEIP.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref RStatsNetworkInterface

  RStatsNetworkInterface:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
      Description: Interface for RStudio Connection
      GroupSet:
      - !Ref RstatsEC2SecurityGroup
      SourceDestCheck: true

  RStatsEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: RStatsEIPAssociation
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPair
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref RStatsNetworkInterface
          DeviceIndex: 0
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: RStudio
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          #install R
          yum install -y R
          #install RStudio-Server 1.0.153 (2017-07-20)
          wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
          yum install -y --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
          rm rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
          #install shiny and shiny-server (2017-08-25)
          R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
          wget https://download3.rstudio.org/centos6.3/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.9.923-x86_64.rpm
          yum install -y --nogpgcheck shiny-server-1.5.9.923-x86_64.rpm
          #add user(s)
          useradd ${InitialUser}
          echo ${InitialUser}:${InitialPassword} | chpasswd
          # install curl
          yum install -y curl-devel
          # Use Shiny server
          /opt/shiny-server/bin/deploy-example user-dirs
          mkdir /home/${InitialUser}/ShinyApps
          # copy in some test data
          cp -R /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps/hello /home/${InitialUser}/ShinyApps/

Outputs:
  RStudioURL:
    Value: !Join [":", [!GetAtt RStatsEC2Instance.PublicDnsName, "8787"]]
  ShinyStudioURL:
    Value: !Join [":", [!GetAtt RStatsEC2Instance.PublicDnsName, !Sub "3838/${InitialUser}/MyApp"]]
  PublicIp:
    Value: !GetAtt RStatsEC2Instance.PublicIp
```

I spun up five instances with this template. I'd like to spin up a couple more, but I'm running into this error.

```
The maximum number of addresses has been reached. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AddressLimitExceeded; Request ID: 6c8acda5-b399-4239-aa30-265a4371bc6d)
```

I tried to create more IP addresses from the Amazon pool, but I hit this error.

```
The maximum number of addresses has been reached.
```

Can I reuse addresses that I already have?

Comment: Why do you need an elastic IP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elastic IPs primary use case is to enable moving an IP from one instance to another instance in the case of instance failure, as an HA solution.

If you just need the RStudio instance to be publicly reachable then enable a public IP (not an Elastic IP) at launch time. Do this using `AssociatePublicIpAddress` on the relevant [AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html).

Comment: Where do I get the IP address from?

Comment: One of the reference attributes on the created EC2 instance is its PublicIpAddress.